# Request for examples to show various types of subproblems in dynamic programming

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, dynamic-programming

Chapter 6 of ["Algorithms" by Dasgupta, Papadimitriou, and Vazirani](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0073523402) summarizes four types of subproblems that are quite common in dynamic programming. They are

1. prefix/postfix of a string/sequence/array
2. both prefixes/postfixes of a pair of strings/sequences/arrays
3. an interval of a string/sequence/array
4. a rooted subtree

What are the other types of subproblems (and examples/references) for dynamic programming?

---

***Added:*** In a [comment](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5635/if-you-could-rename-dynamic-programming#comment15133_5636) on [this post](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/5635/12739), JeffE mentioned:

> Tables are sometimes used. Dynamic programming over trees (for example: maximum independent set) doesn't normally use a table [=array] to memoize the recurrence; it uses a tree, or in some cases a tree of arrays, or an array of trees, or in some cases a Cartesian product of trees. Similarly for dynamic programming over dags or dynamic programming over tree decompositions for graphs of bounded treewidth.

I would like to know dynamic programming examples over, e.g., a tree of arrays, an array of trees, a Cartesian product of trees, tree decompositions, or more general graphs.

Comment: This is a bit broad.  Are there any particular data types you are interested in, other than strings/sequences/arrays/trees?

Comment: @D.W. Please see my update.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need could be found on [Topcoder.com](https://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=ProblemArchive) (TCC for short).

Start with [Dumitru](https://www.topcoder.com/members/Dumitru)'s [tutorial](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/dynamic-programming-from-novice-to-advanced/).
Done that, you should be able to integrate the DP technique on various structures, like *2D grids*, *narrow ribbons*, *convex polygons*, etc. to name just a few.

An archive of DP problem on TCC: https://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=ProblemArchive&sc=2&sd=desc&cat=Dynamic+Programming

And the **match editorial** is the best collection: https://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=match_editorials&d2=archive

I have learnt so much from these. Unfortunately, this editorial series stopped since 2008. From that time on, the SRMs are only discussed in the forum like these more recent SRMs:
https://www.topcoder.com/blog/single-round-match-735-editorials/

A tagged search produces this: https://www.topcoder.com/blog/tag/srm-editorials/
So you may easily access all the recent SRMs.

**SRM**: *Single Round Match* (TCC is the arena of *online competitive programming*)

---

Please note that TCC has been gone through various reconstruction (since the integration with Data Science market). As a (unwanted) consequence, many links are broken but can be fixed by modifying some middle parts (as often the cases for decades-old websites)